# Linear maps gives continuous maps between one-point compactification?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, spheres

If $V\longrightarrow W$ is a linear map, say an orthogonal projection, it gives a map $S^V\longrightarrow S^W$. Is this map between spheres continuous and well-defined?

Comment: No, not necessarily... Have you tried to see it even on a simple example? In general only *proper* maps induce a continuous map on the one-point compactification.

Comment: Then how can we construct a continuous map from $S^V$ to $S^W$ when dimV is bigger than dimW? Thanks.